# issue with select clause in linq - to - entities query

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Hello I'm using code first approach and I defined the following model:

```
public partial class tmmodel
    {
        public tmmodel()
        {
            this.tmmodel_L10n = new HashSet<tmmodel_L10n>();
        }

        public int id { get; set; }
        public int Order { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<tmmodel_L10n> tmmodel_L10n { get; set; }
    }


  public partial class tmmodel_L10n
    {
        public int modelid { get; set; }
        public int CultureId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }

        public virtual tmmodel tmmodel { get; set; }
    }
```

So I want to get in an anonymous class - the id, Active and order property of my tmodel along with teh title in tmodel_L10:

With Linq i MANAGED TO GET the result - but when I try to use Linq - to - sql - I have some problems :

```
 var items = from i in dc.tmmodel
              join l10n in dc.tmmodel_L10n on new { i.id, cid = 1 } equals new { l10n.modelid, cid = l10n.CultureId }
                select new
                {
                    id = i.id,
                      i.Order,
                      i.Active,
                      l10n.Title,
                  };
```

Here is my - linq to entites query and you can see that I don't have any access to the Title property:

```
 var linqtosqlitems = dc.tmmodel
.Include(x => x.tmmodel_L10n)
.Select(l => new {id = l.id,l.Active,**l.tmmodel_L10n.??**}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

By using include Linq Creates an Enumarable of your "child" table because it can be one to many relationship. If You are sure there is only one record in "child table" You can go like:

```
var linqtosqlitems = dc.tmmodel
.Include(x => x.tmmodel_L10n)
.Select(l => new {id = l.id,l.Active,l.tmmodel_L10n.FirstOrDefault().Title}).ToList();
```